# How can i match the background color of a button with the foreground of another item

Tags: c#, button, windows-phone-8, background

So I have a button in which the background needs to match a RadioButton foreground color.
I've edited the template of the button to have its corners round, under the Value tag here:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundColor}"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

I don't know what to change, I've even tried to change it when the button is pressed like so:

```
private void seeWhy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        button.Background = checkedRadioButton.Foreground;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/quiz.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have multiple RadioButtons with different colors and want to change the background color of one button based on the selected color.

Regardless, this should still be helpful even if I am wrong.

I would suggest adding an event handler during the constructor as well as storing the button

```
coolButton = button1;
radioButton1.Checked += changeColor;
radioButton2.Checked += changeColor;
```

Then the event handler:

```
private void changeColor(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    coolButton.Background = ((RadioButton) sender).Foreground;
}
```